# Can anyone help me troubleshoot a script to move/delete a row from one sheet to another in google sheets apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet called "Inventory" below

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hYkTQFhTREh-d-6kuKhDAMZUOYKu4pWyFPh61EmEIPo/edit?usp=sharing

Row K of Inventory contains a dropdown menu, I am attempting to move and delete the row if the value "Sold" is selected and add it to the next tabbed sheet called "Delivery Status." I would like it to append to the 2nd row below the headers on the destination sheet. I also want the action to be reversed if "Returned to Catalog" is selected on the Delivery Status sheet. Any help is greatly appreciated!

What am I missing here?:

```
function onEdit(e){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sourceSheet = e.range.getSheet();
    if(sourceSheet.getSheetName() === 'Inventory'){
        var row = e.range.getRow();
        var rowRange = sourceSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn());
        var rowValues = rowRange.getValues()[0];
        if(rowValues[10] === "Sold"){
            var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Delivery Status");
            targetSheet.insertRowAfter(1);
            var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(2, 1);
            rowRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);      
            sourceSheet.deleteRow(row);
        }     
    } 
}

function onEdit(e){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sourceSheet = e.range.getSheet();
    if(sourceSheet.getSheetName() === 'Delivery Status'){
        var row = e.range.getRow();
        var rowRange = sourceSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn());
        var rowValues = rowRange.getValues()[0];
        if(rowValues[10] === "Return to catalog"){
            var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Inventory");
            targetSheet.insertRowAfter(1);
            var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(2, 1);
            rowRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);      
            sourceSheet.deleteRow(row);
        }     
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In your showing script, there are 2 `onEdit` functions. In this case, when a cell is edited, one of them is run. By this, I think that your script is not correctly run.
- And, in your script, when the value is copied from "Inventory" to "Delivery Status", a new row is inserted into the 2nd row using `targetSheet.insertRowAfter(1)`. By this, the dropdown list of column "K" is not existing.
- In your Spreadsheet, the values of the dropdown list of column "K" of "Delivery Status" sheet are "Sold" and "Return to Catalog". But, in your script, `Return to catalog` is used for comparing the values. In this case, `if (rowValues[10] === "Return to catalog") {}` is always `false`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your showing script is modified.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!onEdit1(e)) onEdit2(e);
}

function onEdit1(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sourceSheet.getSheetName() === 'Inventory') {
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var rowRange = sourceSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn());
    var rowValues = rowRange.getValues()[0];
    if (rowValues[10] === "Sold") {
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Delivery Status");
      targetSheet.insertRowAfter(1);
      targetSheet.getRange(3, 11).copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(2, 11));
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(2, 1);
      rowRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
      sourceSheet.deleteRow(row);
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function onEdit2(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sourceSheet.getSheetName() === 'Delivery Status') {
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var rowRange = sourceSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn());
    var rowValues = rowRange.getValues()[0];
    if (rowValues[10] === "Return to Catalog") {
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Inventory");
      targetSheet.insertRowAfter(1);
      targetSheet.getRange(3, 11).copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(2, 11));
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(2, 1);
      rowRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
      sourceSheet.deleteRow(row);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the above script might be able to be modified a bit simpler as follows.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  // This object is created from the explanation of your question.
  const obj = {
    "Inventory": { condition: "Sold", dst: "Delivery Status" },
    "Delivery Status": { condition: "Return to Catalog", dst: "Inventory" },
  };
  const { range, source } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
  const rowRange = sheet.getRange(range.rowStart, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  const v = rowRange.getValues()[0];
  if (!Object.keys(obj).includes(sheetName) || obj[sheetName].condition != v[10]) return;
  const targetSheet = source.getSheetByName(obj[sheetName].dst);
  targetSheet.insertRowAfter(1);
  targetSheet.getRange(3, 11).copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(2, 11));
  const targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(2, 1);
  rowRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  sheet.deleteRow(range.rowStart);
}
```